# Using flags=0 for revcmsg and sendmsg

Tags: sockets, qnx, recvmsg

What is the expected behaviour of `recvmsg`/`sendmsg` when `flags=0`?

I came across an example in some vsomeip 3.3 code ([here for example](https://github.com/COVESA/vsomeip/blob/0ba13d3e11307cbf4459d3fc8ea13ae82f731a7d/implementation/endpoints/src/credentials.cpp#L73)) that I'm debugging (ported to QNX) and I'm unsure how to interpret this.  I even see some SO questions that use 0 for flags.

The docs for [recvmsg](https://linux.die.net/man/2/recvmsg) say:

> The *flags* argument to a `recv()` call is formed by *ORing* **one or more** of the following values:

(I'm on QNX, and [they specify the same](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/7.1/index.html#com.qnx.doc.neutrino.lib_ref/topic/r/recvmsg.html))

I'm confused because the flags can provide opposite behaviour, *i.e.* `MSG_DONTWAIT` *vs* `MSG_WAITALL`, so I don't know what to should expect from `flags=0`. (particularly because both those flags seem to sometimes result in an `EAGAIN` error code on QNX for me right now.)

`sendmsg` docs do say "0 or more of the following flags", but I'm still confused about that I should expect there too.

When I read some variants of the Linux implementations, it suggests that with `flags=0` many sections are just skipped, but I'd like something more authoritative.